# Transforming XML to another XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform an XML file into another XML using XSLT, but all I get is a blank page.

I'm trying to transform this XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xslt.xslt"?>
<ForskoleAnsokan>
  
  <Vardnadshavare>
    <Vardtagare>
      <Fornamn>Arne</Fornamn>
      <Efternamn>Jonsson</Efternamn>
      <Personnummer>8802202220</Personnummer>
      <Adress>Galavägen 13</Adress>
      <Postnummer>46444</Postnummer>
      <Postort>Trandhatan</Postort>
      <Kontakt>072283832</Kontakt>
    </Vardtagare>
    <Vardtagare>
      <Fornamn>Gunilla</Fornamn>
      <Efternamn>Jonsson</Efternamn>
      <Personnummer>8702102110</Personnummer>
      <Adress>Galavägen 13</Adress>
      <Postnummer>46444</Postnummer>
      <Postort>Trandhatan</Postort>
      <Kontakt>073262613</Kontakt>
    </Vardtagare>
  </Vardnadshavare>

</ForskoleAnsokan>
```

Using this XSLT

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <begaranominkomstuppgift>
        <xsl:for-each select="ForskoleAnsokan/Vardnadshavare/Vardtagare">
          <person>
            <xsl:attribute name="Personnummer">
              <xsl:value-of select="@Personnummer"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <Fornamn>
              <xsl:value-of select="@Fornamn"/>
            </Fornamn>
            <Efternamn>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Efternamn"/>
            </Efternamn>
          </person>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </begaranominkomstuppgift>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

into this xml

```html
<begaranominkomstuppgift>
      <person personnummer="8802202220">
          <fornamn>Arne</fornamn>
          <efternamn>Jonsson</efternamn>
        
  </person>
      <person personnummer="8702102110">
          <fornamn>Gunilla</fornamn>
          <efternamn>Jonsson</efternamn>
        
  </person>
</begaranominkomstuppgift>
```

But all I get is a blank page

Comment: Why is there no data in your desired output?

Comment: Your question title is a very unhelpful one. "Transforming XML to another XML with XSLT" fits about _all_ XSLT questions on Stackoverflow. Perhaps you could edit it and try to find something more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text to be displayed, you need to change the output to html. Change your xslt.xsl file to this :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <begaranominkomstuppgift>
    <xsl:for-each select="ForskoleAnsokan/Vardnadshavare/Vardtagare">
      <person>
        <xsl:attribute name="Personnummer">
          <xsl:value-of select="Personnummer"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <Fornamn>
          <xsl:value-of select="Fornamn"/>
        </Fornamn>
        <Efternamn>
        <xsl:value-of select="Efternamn"/>
        </Efternamn>
      </person>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </begaranominkomstuppgift>
</xsl:template>
```

Notice that I removed the `@`as they are used to access attribute not simple elements.

Also note that your xml was actually already transforming, but as you stated that it display as a blank page, I supposed you are trying to view in browser and then need to change the output to html. For example, if you inspect the page, you will see that the xml is outputed.

Also note that changing the output to html won't display the actual XML, but will interpret it as html and then output some content. **To see your exact xml, simply right click on the page and click inspect.**

Also note that this won't work on chrome.

Comment: Awesome, yea Chrome was the problem, i actually saw results in IE.

Comment: Here more information about that : Chrome block that for some security reason which disallow to acces local file from same folder. You might try to open chrome using the flag --allow-file-access-from-files and see if it fixes the issue. I did not add it to the answer as I'm not sure if it will works and can't test atm.

Answer (score 1):

Change your XSL to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <begaranominkomstuppgift>
        <xsl:for-each select="ForskoleAnsokan/Vardnadshavare/Vardtagare">
          <person>
            <xsl:attribute name="Personnummer">
              <xsl:value-of select="Personnummer"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <Fornamn>
              <xsl:value-of select="Fornamn"/>
            </Fornamn>
            <Efternamn>
            <xsl:value-of select="Efternamn"/>
            </Efternamn>
          </person>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </begaranominkomstuppgift>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You were using the attribute accessor (@) in your value-of calls, but those data items are just elements, not attributes.

Comment: Also, curious what language that is?

Comment: Tried it, nothing changes. swedish

Comment: See http://xsltransform.net/bdxtq2, the change should help. But if you run XSLT in the browser, as the use of `<?xml-stylesheet?>` suggests, then don't expect any useful output with XML to XML transformation, unless the target format is XHTML or SVG the browser knows to render.

Comment: Oh, yea im using it in chrome, is there any way to make it work in chrome ?